# what is the significance of @Component annotation for Filter in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Why do we need to use @Component annotation for Filter in spring boot, why we can't use @Configuration annotation.

**Please note: I am not trying to register filter in FilterRegistrationBean.**

Answer (score 6):

`@Configuration` indicates that the class may contain `@Bean` methods and should be processed to define those beans in the application context. This isn't something that a `Filter` does so it should not be annotated with `@Configuration`.

If you look at the source for `@Configuration`, you'll see that [it's annotated with `@Component`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/e4e667acdb774b45164f3ec345bfdf9e406e537f/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.java#L424). `@Configuration` is a special kinds of `@Component`. In this case, all you need is for the `Filter` itself to be a bean. It doesn't have any `@Bean` methods so it's sufficient for it to be annotated with `@Component`. This will ensure that the `Filter` is a bean and Spring Boot will the register the `Filter` bean with the servlet container without any need for a `FilterRegistrationBean` and without wasting resources unnecessarily processing your `Filter`'s class looking for `@Bean` methods.